# Selfnormalizing sub-algebra and direct sum decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

I got the following setting:

Consider the decomposition $L=H+\sum_{\alpha\in \phi}L_{\alpha}$,

where the sum is a direct sum, the $L_{\alpha}$ are the root spaces and $H$ is nilpotent (because its abelian).

This is from the last step of the proof of Serre's theorem (c.f. James E. Humphreys Thm. 18.3).

The question is now: Why $H$ is self-normalizing?

Comment: Because you know that $H$ acts diagonally on each of the spaces in the decomposition. Try to write up what happens when you act on some $h\in H$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  What does "acts diagonally.." mean? And why this is a contradiction?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So, I guess I should consider $[h_i,x_j]=\langle \alpha_j,\alpha_i\rangle x_j$ (The Weyl-Relations) and similarly for $y_j$? But why this is a contradiction/ a problem? Edit: Because the RHS $\langle \alpha_j,\alpha_i\rangle x_j$ is not an element of $H$, right?

Comment: Well, when would that be in $H$ itself?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If $x_j$ would be in $H$ which is wrong, because the sum is direct?:)

Comment: Right, so now you need to extend this to an arbitrary linear combination which is not in $H$, but the idea is the same

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Alright, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Humphreys book it is proved long before Theorem 18.3, that every Cartan subalgebra $H$ is self-normalizing. Also, there is the following exercise in Humphreys book (and since you say that $H$ is abelian, I suppose that this is what you want):

Exercise 5: If L is semisimple, H a maximal toral subalgebra, prove that H is self-normalizing.

The solution is online [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwivtdLP0fzKAhXIvhQKHaJCDXYQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ualberta.ca%2F~zhchang%2FResearch%2FNotes_01_STLA.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGfiEYT2ENXXHzNS1cWOGmUfyXh9w&sig2=W8U_y49e_T5jSs3YCAL00w).